# Generate ZMK using Clear components

Tags: components, key, using, hsm

I need to "Generate ZMK using Clear components".

Could you please let me know how to generate ZMK using clear components using software.

Is HSM (hardware ) mandatory for this or it is possible using software as well? If yes how?